# OData: query containing array index

Tags: odata

I'm struggling with the following (simplified for the sake of explanation) `OData` query. The following query contains an index array:

```
/method?$filter=(substringof('X',JB.JJB[0].J.prop) eq true) //look at JJB[0]
```

`OData` returns the following response:

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. Syntax error at position (where there is [0])
```

How can I write a compliant-OData syntax query containing a reference to an index array?

Comment: OData has no such concept for "array" and "array index".

Comment: And you can provide your model scenario, so that maybe I can help find a work-around